# Show Kit Specification

Tags: acumatica

In Sales Order entry, I added a toolbar button "Kit Details". How do I popup screen to display the specification of the current selected kit item ?

[image: kit details]

Comment: Did you tried anything yet?

Comment: I assume you are simply trying to open the kit page/graph? look for examples calling PXRedirectHelper or PXRedirectRequiredException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open KitAssembly use the following code in your action handler:

```
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Kit Details", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = true)]
public virtual IEnumerable KitDetail(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    // Add error handling if necessary
    KitAssemblyEntry kitAssemblyEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<KitAssemblyEntry>();
    kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Current = kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Search<INKitRegister.inventoryID>(Base.Transactions.Current.InventoryID);
    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(kitAssemblyEntry, true, "IN Kit Assembly") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
}
```

When you invoke the KitDetail action:
[image]

It will open the Kit Assembly for the selected SOLine.InventoryID:
[image]

**EDIT**

Yes INKitSpecMaint is the correct graph for displaying Kit Specification.
When Search doesn't work you can use Select to initialize your new graph:

```
[PXProcessButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Kit Details", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = true)]
public virtual IEnumerable KitDetail(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    INKitSpecMaint kitSpecification = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INKitSpecMaint>();
    kitSpecification.Hdr.Current = PXSelect<INKitSpecHdr, Where<INKitSpecHdr.kitInventoryID, Equal<Required<INKitSpecHdr.kitInventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, Base.Transactions.Current.InventoryID);
    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(kitSpecification, true, "Kit Specification") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm wanting to show the Kit Specification(IN209500), not the Kit Assembly(IN307000). What should be the correct graph to use ? Tried INKitSpecMaint, but it's giving me all sorts of error like it doesn't have a Search definition etc.